# Realizing a group as a cocompact lattice

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $ \Gamma $ be a finitely generated torsion free group. Does there always exist a Lie group $ G $ containing $ \Gamma $ (or really a subgroup isomorphic to $ \Gamma $) such that $ G/\Gamma $ is compact?

In other words, can every finitely generated torsion free group be realized as a cocompact lattice in some Lie group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

1. Why yes: Every finitely-generated group $\Gamma$ is countable and every countable group with discrete topology is a Lie group. Clearly, $\Gamma$ is a (cocompact) lattice in $\Gamma$.
2. However, I do not think you are interested in Lie groups with infinitely many components. Hence, suppose that $G$ is a Lie group with finitely many components and $G_0< G$ is the identity component. For every lattice $\Gamma< G$, $\Gamma_0:= \Gamma\cap G_0$ is a lattice in $G_0$; the index $|\Gamma: \Gamma_0|$ is, of course, finite.

Connected Lie groups need not be linear (over real numbers), but one can use the adjoint representation $Ad_{G_0}$ to obtain a faithful matrix representation of $G_0/Z(G_0)$, where $Z(G_0)$ is the center of $G_0$.

In particular, the quotient of $\Gamma_0$ by a subgroup of its center (namely, $\Gamma_0\cap Z(G_0)$) is a matrix group. There are many algebraic restrictions on finitely generated matrix groups, for instance, they are *residually finite*, hence, always admit proper finite index subgroups.

Thus, to get an example of a finitely-generated group which is not a lattice in any Lie group with finitely many components, you can take any infinite finitely generated group without proper finite index subgroups, e.g. the [Higman group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group) given by the presentation:

$$
\langle a, b, c, d| aba^{-1}=b^2, bcb^{-1}=c^2, cdc^{-1}=d^2, dad^{-1}=a^2\rangle. 
$$

There are many other examples, for instance, due to the fact that lattices have finite virtual cohomological dimension, etc.

Comment: Is there a compact aspherical manifold $ M $ with fundamental group the Higman group? And, if so, does that mean such an $ M $ is not homeomoprhic to $ \Gamma \backslash G/K $ for any Lie group $ G $, maximal compact subgroup $ K $, and lattice $ \Gamma $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira: If you mean "a compact manifold without boundary" then such a manifold does not exist. If you mean "a compact manifold with boundary" then there is such a 4-dimensional manifold. It is not even homotopy-equivalent to $\Gamma\backslash G/K$ for the reasons stated in my answer (assuming $\Gamma$ is torsion-free).

Comment: Ah I guess saying "closed manifold" manifold is less ambiguous than "compact manifold" if I don't want a boundary. Do you know of any aspherical closed manifold which is not homeomorphic to $ \Gamma \backslash G /K $ for any Lie group $ G $, maximal compact $ K $ and lattice $ \Gamma $ ? (I'll probably just make this a new question but I was wondering if anything came to mind immediately for you )

Comment: Yes, of course. I think you know them as well (at least, in dimension 3):   Take any non-geometrizable closed irreducible 3-manifold. Examples exist in all dimensions $>2$.

Comment: Ok true that follows immediately from geometrization. Without the full power of geometrization can I say something like: the connected sum of any two closed aspherical manifolds in dimension $ \geq 3 $ should give an example of a closed aspherical manifold which is not $ \Gamma \backslash G/K $. I guess the idea is that in dimensions $ n \geq 3 $ the fundamental group of the connected sum is a free product and free products cannot be be subgroups of matrix groups (except in a $ SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ subgroup)? Or what's the right way to see this in higher dimensions (without geometrization)?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira In dimensions $\ge 3$ connected sums like that are never aspherical. The simplest examples I know that work in all dimensions is to take two copies of  $S\times T^k$, where $S$ is genus $\ge 1$ surface with one boundary component, and glue them along the boundaries (which are $\cong T^{k+1}$) by some randomly chosen affine homeomorphism. Such manifolds never admit homogeneous metrics, but are closed and aspherical.